# LLVM Metadata reference instruction

Tags: llvm, metadata

I want to a create an MDNode that references another instruction.

```
MDNode *mdNode = MDNode::get(ctx, llvm::LocalAsMetadata::get(decider)); // decider is an instruction
phi->setMetadata("carry", mdNode); // phi is an instruction
```

Unfortunately the verifier fails with "Invalid operand for global metadata!" I'm starting to think that this is not possible with the current Metadata API (it seems it might have been handled in the past). Any thoughts?

Comment: The message says that a *local* is not valid for *global* metadata. Did you accidentally set this metadata on a GlobalVariable, Function or other object outside decider's function?

Comment: No. Even if I use a unique name for each piece of metadata I still get the error.

Comment: You're right. LocalAsMetadata is only to be used by MetadataAsValue.

Comment: Hmmm... this seems like a failing of the LLVM API. It shouldn't be so general as to allow compilation in this case.